# Add hyperlink to articles FAQ/introduction post

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

The 'Articles' section under the Activity tab simply informs the user that they haven't created any articles:

[image]

The 'Followed posts' section also adds a hyperlink to the [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/258356) that introduced the feature:

[image]

Should there be a similar hyperlink in the former case as well?

Comment: +1'ed this, due to consistency across the site. I believe this should be done, not only due to the aforementioned reason but also for new users. A new user has absolutely no idea about this feature, and has a bit of ambiguity, since it's just the literal word "*article*" (I mean, that's not really the main feature of SO/SE, so yeah...). Every bit counts.

Comment: I've been using the site for over 10 years and I haven't got a clue what an article is. I assume it's something related either to Documentation 1.0 or Documentation 2.0?

Comment: @Lundin even I don't have a clue. Hence a link would be really helpful.